# Any software to modify within images? Not just things like the size of the image

Tags: images, image-manipulation

Lets say I have two jpg files. I want to create a series of images, where I move one of the images across the face of the other image. I can already do this in any number of graphical editors, but it takes time to perform the action and then to do a filesave.

But it would be much more useful if I could use a command, or a software to do such a job for me. For example, if I could specify to insert a jpg at a certain offset, and then move it in a certain direction a given number of pixels each time, for a given number of images.

Is there anything which can provide such a functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick's [`composite`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php) tool seems ideally suited to this. You'd do something like

```
composite -geometry +20+20 foreground.jpg background.jpg composite1.jpg
composite -geometry +30+20 foreground.jpg background.jpg composite2.jpg
```

etc. to produce `composite1.jpg` containing `foreground.jpg` laid over `background.jpg` at position 20×20, and `composite2.jpg` in the same way but at position 30×20.

The ImageMagick web site has [quite a few composition examples](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#composition).

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Thank you so much. Worked exactly how I wanted it to.